# Ransack search, how to search for each word by splitting input search parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, ransack

I am currently experimenting using the `ransack gem` to conduct a search on a model in Rails.  As it stands I am using the basic setup.

Controller:

```
def index
  @q = Person.search(params[:q])
  @people = @q.result(:distinct => true)
end
```

View:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name_cont %>
   <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I have managed to find lot of information about conducting searches on multiple fields, however, I haven't managed to find anything to help me to split up the `:q` parameter and thereby enable me to search for each of the (unknown quantity of) words in the search string entered in the form of `search for ??? AND ??? AND ??? ...`, rather than searching for the entire string in one section

Is anybody able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spent a chunk of time looking into this with no results, I opted for a custom, non-ransack option which works perfectly well.

In `View.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag siteindex_search_allproducts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <b>Search: </b> <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

In `Controller`

```
@findproducts = Allproduct.order('price ASC').search(params[:search])
```

In `model.rb`

```
def self.search(*args)
   return [] if args.blank?
   cond_text, cond_values = [], []
   args.each do |str|
       next if str.blank?  
       cond_text << "( %s )" % str.split.map{|w| "product_name LIKE ? "}.join(" AND ")
       cond_values.concat(str.split.map{|w| "%#{w}%"})
    end
    all :conditions =>  [cond_text.join(" AND "), *cond_values]
end
```

Comment: I am trying this, but I'm getting an error on the last line "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

Answer (score 7):

Here's an answer that uses a custom Ransack predicate:

```
# config/initializers/ransack.rb

Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'has_any_term',
  arel_predicate: 'matches_any',
  formatter: proc { |v| v.scan(/\"(.*?)\"|(\w+)/).flatten.compact.map{|t| "%#{t}%"} },
  validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
  type: :string
end

Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'has_every_term',
  arel_predicate: 'matches_all',
  formatter: proc { |v| v.scan(/\"(.*?)\"|(\w+)/).flatten.compact.map{|t| "%#{t}%"} },
  validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
  type: :string
end
```

The search form would use the custom predicate as such:

```
# In your view

# to search for any of the terms existing in my_field 
=search_form_for @search do |f|
  =f.search_field  :my_field_has_any_term


# to search for all of the terms existing in my_field 
=search_form_for @search do |f|
  =f.search_field  :my_field_has_every_term
```

Double-quoted terms will be recognized automatically.

Comment: I'd propose to use `[[:alpha]]` instead of `\w` in the regex though, as otherwise this will split words with Umlauts in them.

Comment: (or `[[:alnum:]]` if you want to include numbers as well)