# Rails search in two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and I want to make searches, I used ransack but not successful. I have a textfield in the navbar to find my aplication like this

layouts/_navigation.html.erb

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="header">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BLABLABLA</a>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
          <div class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.search_field :nombre_cont, class: "form-control" %> 
            </div>
              <%= f.submit "Buscar" , class: "btn btn-success btn-primary" %>
            </div>
       <% end %> 
    </div> <!--/.navbar-collapse -->

  </div>
```

would search for any word entered in the fields of two models in my HomeController

db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140324120403) do

  create_table "departamentos", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.integer  "interno"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "funcionarios", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.string   "apellido"
    t.string   "cargo"
    t.integer  "departamento_id"
    t.integer  "interno"
    t.string   "correo"
    t.date     "cumpleanio"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

end
```

this would be the SQL query I want

```
SELECT funcionarios.* 
FROM funcionarios 
INNER JOIN departamentos ON departamentos.id = funcionarios.departamento_id 
WHERE 
(funcionarios.nombre LIKE '%VALUE%' OR 
funcionarios.apellido LIKE '%VALUE%' OR 
departamentos.nombre LIKE '%VALUE%' OR
departamentos.interno LIKE '%VALUE%')
```

any idea how to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about try the following:

```
Funcionario.joins(:departamentos).where("nombre like '%?%' OR apellido LIKE '%?%' OR departamentos.nombre LIKE '%?%' OR departamentos.interno LIKE '%?%'", VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Where should I write that line in a method in the controller or as a model and I can use on my view? Sorry I ask these questions I'm working with rails for some time but still do not understand it at all: (

Comment: @Adh761 no problem at all! You can use it in your controllers if you want but a better approach is to put it inside your Funcionario model as a scope => http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes . I hope that helps :).

Comment: ok thanks, I created the search method in the model, 
in my HomeController index `@Funcionarios = Funcionarios.search.(params [:q])` and then as I would put in layout / _navigation.html.erb?

Comment: Yes you can use this @funcionarios instance variable in your view, where you want it.

Comment: something similar to this answer right [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611869/ransack-search-how-to-search-for-each-word-by-splitting-input-search-parameter?rq=1]

Comment: If you just want to see the results without any formatting you can just say on your view(app/views/home/your_action.html.erb) something like this: <%= @funcionarios %>. This will print on the page the results. If you want it on the navigation.html.erb you should put the Funcionarios = Funcionarios.search.(params [:q]) on the action that renders this view/layout.

Comment: Pleasure all mine! :)

Comment: hi @nronas, its me again, i writed this in my view/layout/_navigation.tml.erb `<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :q, nil %>
        <%= submit_tag "Buscar"%>
      <%= end %>`i don't know what i do wrong because said **No route matches {:controller=>"home", :action=>"buscar"}**

Comment: Hi @Adh761, what `bundle exec rake routes` gives you? Also `rails -v` and `ruby -v` what it give u. Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for your time, it was a problem with paths